# Ubuntu 16.04 phpinfo shows blank Page

Tags: php

After installing **MYSQL APACHE2 and PHP7** when I go to see phpinfo page it shows a **blank page**.

During installation process I am not able to install **libapache2-mod-php7** in **Ubuntu 16.04**. It give error like this: "**Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my system, the package name is `libapache2-mod-php7.0`.  Try `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0` to install that package.

That said, you should not need that package to get the `phpinfo()` function working in a PHP script.

Comment: Thanks bro. After installing libapache2-mod-php7.0 now its working.